# Nginx + Gunicorn + Django: displays Nginx default page every 3 times

Tags: django, nginx, server, gunicorn

I have a Django app on Gunicorn 20.1.0 (:8000), served with Nginx 1.18.0 as the main server ([link to the website](https://stackoverflow.com)) on Debian 11.2:

Nginx <-:8000-> Gunicorn <-> Django

The server displays the Nginx default template every three times (1st request, 4, 7, 10, so on). Here is a snippet of the Nginx access log (notice the pattern in the bytes sent):

```
89.xx.xxx.xx - - [05/Jul/2023:11:37:23 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
89.xx.xxx.xx - - [05/Jul/2023:12:01:51 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6723 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
89.xx.xxx.xx - - [05/Jul/2023:12:01:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6723 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
89.xx.xxx.xx - - [05/Jul/2023:12:01:53 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
89.xx.xxx.xx - - [05/Jul/2023:12:01:54 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6723 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
89.xx.xxx.xx - - [05/Jul/2023:12:01:54 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6723 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
...
```

There's no error in Nginx or Gunicorn `error.log` files (**both server and site specific logs are blank.** previously I had some errors so I'm assured that the logging is not flawed). Other requests (2nd,3rd,5th,...) are responded properly and as expected (no problems whatsoever).

I know It must be Gunicorn failing to respond but I have no clue where should I look at to figure out a solution.

So far, I tried to increase the timeout limit of both Gunicorn (`timeout`) and Nginx (the server responds pretty quick). It should be noted that the server has plenty of free resources. I also ran the Gunicorn with `--log-level=debug` but the `error.log` shows nothing related.

Here is the Gunicorn config file:

```
"""Gunicorn *development* config file"""
timeout = 120
wsgi_app = "project.wsgi:application"
loglevel = "debug"
workers = 2
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
reload = True
accesslog = errorlog = "/var/log/gunicorn/dev.log"
capture_output = True
pidfile = "/var/run/gunicorn/dev.pid"
daemon = True
```

and the Nginx server's:

```
server_tokens               off;
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/e-damac.ir.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/e-damac.ir.error.log;

server {
  server_name               e-damac.ir www.e-damac.ir;
  listen                    80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  }
  location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /var/www/html/e-damac.ir/static/;
  }
}
```

I haven't edited the `nginx.conf` file and it's in the original condition.

Any suggestions or diagnosis methods would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** As gunicorn's access log suggests it's never received the requests in question.

Comment: im not sure about this, but everything might be fine. and only for this page you just need multiple requests and responses...

Comment: @scaryhamid I'm using 2 workers for the page, which is probably more than enough as there is only one user, me! anything particular in mind?

Comment: as i just said, if you are not getting errors and everything is working fine, then why change something when its working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the default nginx page you need to remember the flow. Nginx -> gunicorn -> django. So if you have a different rendered page that is related to nginx the issue probably lies in nginx and not gunicorn. I'd just go find the conf server definition that points to nginx's default page and comment it out or remove it altogether. You most likely have over lapping server definitions going on right now.

Comment: Overlapping was my initial hypothesis (forgot to mention). I'll try commenting out. Thx.

Comment: turned out I forgot to unlink the `default` configuration file from `sites-enabled` and it also was listening to the port 8000 under some circumstances.